# How to program a toolstrip with textbox font formatting

Tags: vb.net, fonts, crash, formatting, richtextbox

I am making some software in VB.NET that requires a box (RTB) needing all the standard font format buttons. I have a toolstrip with buttons for bold, underline, italics and strikethrough, as well as combobxes for font and font size. but my problem is that i am unable to work out how to actually program these buttons. I am also having problems showing that they are toggled in  the front end, as even tho they all hafve the same code to change their backcolour, they are responding differently.

This is the code that I have so far. http://pastebin.com/E1AHNBpj The form crashes when any of the buttons are pressed or any font settings are changed

Comment: Creating a text editor out of RTB is a favorite Codeproject project.  Avoid reinventing this wheel, google "vb.net richtextbox text editor".

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not re-inventing the wheel, I just want to build my own wheel to prove that I can. Also, this is for a college project. It's way too late to change my idea